# PHP cURL problem with HTML form post method and url

Tags: php, html, forms, curl, submit

The problem with the below code is that the code **stops working if you try to submit more than once.**

Basically; I am trying to make a search bar in my website that would show search results from other websites, maybe this functionality that I am trying to achieve won't work and I should try something different?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="form-0">
        Search: <input type="text" name="search">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        function searchit(){
            $curl = curl_init();
            $qry_str = htmlentities($_POST["search"],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" . $qry_str;
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
            curl_exec($curl);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            echo $result;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
            searchit();
        }
    
    ?>
    </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to give more debugging info about precisely what happens to the code, what response (if any) you get from the Amazon server, etc.

Comment: I get the object not found error, should I  still try to debug?

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the line it occurs on, thanks

Comment: Apparently, the problem was that amazon was blocking my scrapping code. At least other websites work so that’s good enough for me.